# loop over a bunch of urls in batch file

Tags: batch-file, url, for-loop, curl

I am trying to access a bunch of urls (more than 1000). Here are how urls look like

```
url = "http://***/00001"
url = "http://***/00002"
...
url = "http://***/01000"
```

I would like to write a batch file to access those urls automatically. I learned a little bit about how to write a batch file and run it in command line. Something look like this

```
ECHO OFF

FOR /L %i IN (1,1,1000) DO (

    curl -XGET "http://***/0000%i"

    ECHO finish %i
)
```

But it does not work and I'm unable to figure out how to change the '00001' part in the url in the loop. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

On the same idea of @Magoo's answer but working on the string  :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "$BaseUrl=http://****/"

for /l %%a in (1,1,1000) do (
  set "$Number=0000%%a"
  curl -XGET "%$BaseUrl%!$Number:~-5!"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a batch, the `%` for the *metavariable* (`i` in this case) needs to be doubled. Simply double the `%` for each `%i`

---

If you require a 5-digit variable, then

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,1000) DO (
  set /a url=10000000+%%i
  curl -XGET "http://***/!url:~-5!"

  ECHO finish %%i
)
```

Adding 10000000 to `%%i` ensures that the value in `url` is 10000001..10001000 so the last 5 digits can be accessed by `!url:~-5!`.

The key points are that `delayedexpansion` needs to be invoked in order to allow access to the changing value of `url` and that the value must be in an ordinary environment variable in order to allow substringing. Metavariables can't be directly substringed. Naturally, `url` could be assigned directly to the value of `%%i` if `%%i` is varied from 10000001 to 10001000, but that's not as obvious from a code-maintenance perspective.

Comment: Or explained another way, replace all instances of `%i` in your example with `%%i`. On the command line, the correct form is `%i`, but when run from inside a batch file, the correct form is `%%i`.

Comment: @Magoo, it works well. But I got another issue, it seems that my code "0000%%i" will give "000010". however, what I want is actually "00010". How shall I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: @Magoo, thanks for the response. But it does not seem to work. It tries to access "http://***/!url:~-5!", rather than something like "http://***/00012!"

Comment: Works perfectly well for me. I suspect you've omitted to include the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line which invokes `delayedexpansion` mode which permits the `!var!` form to access the current variable value.